# Make JSON request

Tags: json, xml, swift, rest, nsurlsession

I have the following link:

> http://bkrt.dk/api/Place

In this link, there is a list that defult is presented in XML.. However it is able to serve in JSON, if i request it from a service like postman.

So i got the following in swift 3:

```
    func downloadItems() {
    let url: URL = URL(string: urlpath)!
    var session: URLSession!
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default



    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url as URL)

    task.resume()

}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    self.data.append(data)
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to download data")
    }
    else{
        print("Data downloaded")
        self.parseJSON()
    }
}
```

Obviously it gives me the false condition.

But anyway, how do i make my code do a specific GET request, so that my api understands to serve it as json?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Xcode. This is a framework question about NSURLSession.

Comment: what. are you kidding me? its not a framework question. im simply asking how i can make my application accept JSON in its Get request

Comment: Yes, that's a question how to use the framework. Xcode has nothing to do here.

Comment: But swift is used in xCode yes?

Comment: Xcode is an IDE, a tool. You can use other IDEs to write in Swift, such as AppCode. You can use text editors, such as Atom and Sublime. The tool you use to write code has nothing to do with what you are asking, unless you have a problem specific to Xcode, such as Xcode crashing, Interface Builder not working correctly, etc.

Comment: and for that reason (you can call it my igonrance, which was with good intentions) you downvote my question?

Comment: Since you bothered to ask why, I removed the down vote. Please use tags correctly, and do not add tags to the title next time. Cheers

Comment: Good on you. cheers!